# Worldwide site and Datetime storing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, globalization

*I'm looking for the best practice solution.*

Take for example stackoverflow and a question I asked :

I live in Israel , and now the time is :

[image]

I did ask something at ~17:58 ( 3 hours before now)

[image]

Yet  , it does show "3 hours ago" **AND** display UTC time . ( Israel is +2)

So *either* it saves both UTC and my offset

**or** it saves just UTC and in JS at client side it showes me the local time.

now my question is from a DB point of view :

I *can* detect from where the client has connected via JS command :

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); //-120
```

I *could* store it like :

```
data  |    UTCTime          | userOffset
----------------------------------------
 ...    2012-12-24 15:36:31       -2
```

**Question**

- Is this the best solution of storing world wide events (datetimes) ?
- In c# there is a `DateTimeOffset` Structure  type which store the offset inside it .
  is there any equivalent solution in Sql server ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Comment: @Oded but there is a problem. it says _"always keep your date unified"_ but it also says - "_avoid js calculation_" so how did Stackoverflow knows to show me the local datetime ? it has to know my offset . and this is done by either GEOIP service or JS.I would like to know what is wrong with my solution above.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, that doesn't mean it has to be done in JS. The trip to the server, that retrieved all the data, would have modified the time to show the right "offset" as far as "how long ago was this asked." Clearly it's showing the right UTC time - but it knows that based on where you are - that's `3 hours ago`.

Comment: It doesn't do that. It uses the JavaScript `Date` object that will by default give the computer date it is running on (with offset). This is calculated against the UTC date posted on the page.

Comment: @Oded, thanks for the clarification, just learned another little tidbit for future projects!

Comment: @Oded So I was right  ? it saves the utc but the client exposed the offset...right ?

Comment: Yes. That's how it is done on the Stack Exchange sites. If you view the HTML source, you will see the UTC timestamp (usually held in `title` attributes). They simply calculate an offset in JS and replace a div contents with a string. No server side involvement.

Comment: @Oded please have a look at MarcinJuraszek's answer below.(his second comment) he suggest something interesting. he says that the "3 hours ago " is the result of the `rendered page time (utc)` minus `saved post utc time`. so here I dont need the offset at all. please explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices): you should **always keep your date unified**. So UTC would be the best choice.

On the other hand - when you have date in UTC you can easily show it right according to someones timezone (not only for the author, but for everybody).

Comment: see my response to Oded (as a comment)

Comment: The answer is really simple - offset is always the same, no matter which timezone you use :) It can be calculated using current UTC time, because post time is in UTC as well.

Comment: Do you realize that it showed me the UTC ( which is fine) but also my local time ? it knew i'm from  israel . and besided - offset is not always the same.never.

Comment: IT showed you '3 hours ago', which could be calculated using UTC time (18:48 - 15:36)

Comment: Do you mean that  the "3 hours ago " is the result of the `rendered page time (utc)` minus `saved post utc time`. so here I dont need the offset at all......?

Comment: exactly. You don't need anything more that two datetimes (current and saving time) from the same timezone. It can be just server time, so it doesn't have to be your local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. MS SQL Server 2008 introduced [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).

[Here you can find all datetime types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

[And here on how to use them.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)